# Python dictionary key error

Tags: python, dictionary, filenames

I am attempting to run a python program that can run a dictionary from a file with a list of words with each word given a score and standard deviation. My program looks like this:

```
theFile = open('word-happiness.csv', 'r')

theFile.close()



def make_happiness_table(filename):
   ''' make_happiness_table: string -> dict
       creates a dictionary of happiness scores from the given file '''

return {}


make_happiness_table("word-happiness.csv")

table = make_happiness_table("word-happiness.csv")
(score, stddev) = table['hunger']
print("the score for 'hunger' is %f" % score)
```

I have the word 'hunger' in my file but when I run this program to take 'hunger' and return its given score and std deviation, I get:

```
(score, stddev) = table['hunger']
KeyError: 'hunger'
```

How is it that I get a key error even though 'hunger' is in the dictionary?

Comment: can you post full code for make_happiness_table please? based on what you do, you just return an empty dict... or maybe correct your code up here, since it seems a bit messed up (you pass a filename to a function that does nothing, while you open that file way before...)

Comment: print your dictionary (`print(table)`) and check what you have in there. I bet it is not in your dictionary (maybe it is in the file), but Iit would be astonishing if this basic datastructure has a bug.

Comment: That's probably my problem then. I want the dictionary to consist of the words in the .csv file with the given scores and std deviations. How can I do that so it's not an empty dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"hunger"` isn't in the dictionary (that's what the `KeyError` tells you).  The problem is probably your `make_happiness_table` function.  I don't know if you've posted the full code or not, but it doesn't really matter.  At the end of the function, you return an *empty dictionary* (`{}`) regardless of what else went on inside the function.

You probably want to open your file inside that function, create the dictionary and return it.  For example, if your csv file is just 2 columns (separated by a comma), you could do:

```
def make_happiness_table(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
         d = dict( line.split(',') for line in f )
         #Alternative if you find it more easy to understand
         #d = {}
         #for line in f:
         #    key,value = line.split(',')
         #    d[key] = value
    return d
```